# How to set "criter" to filter two letter "accounts" name in Visual Basic?

Tags: vba, filter

I have a dataset with data like this : [Image of Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61sS9.png)

How do I set my filter critieria  to include accounts more than two letters? (or exclude two letter accounts? )

I tried below but it is not working well.

It only includes others :(This only give me blank fields)

```
 wsSophis.Range("$A$1:$AJ$300000").AutoFilter Field:=20,   Criteria1:=Array("*/BNF/*", "*5J*", "*5G*", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Only exclude two letter: (This works too slow and freeze, since data set is big.)

```
 For i = 2 To ilastrow
    If Len(Rng(i, 1)) = 2 Then
       If Not Rng1 Is Nothing Then
        Set Rng1 = Union(Rng1, Rng(i, 1))
        Else
       Set Rng1 = Rng(i, 1)
        End If
    End If
    Next
wsSophis.Range("$A$1:$AJ$200000").AutoFilter Field:=20,     Criteria1:=Array(Rng1), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 0):

`Range("$A$1:$AJ$200000").AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="<>??", Operator:=xlFilterValues`

`Criteria1:="<>??"` is the important bit.